# Dirty animation on iPad's UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, uipageviewcontroller

I'm currently developing the iPad's version of my iPhone app. I have a `UIPageViewController` whose `UIViewController` can go forward or backward.

To do that I use

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

It works well on the iPhone but on the iPad the animation is not very clean. I get some blacks margins when the animation is close to finishing.

I tried to fire the even directly from the `UIPageViewController` and it works fine.

So my guess is that the animation gets dirty because the `subViewController` triggers the page change, and there must be some issue with the `subViewController` not being deallocated at the right moment.

My code in the `UIViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)backHandler:(id)sender {
     UIPageViewController *pvc = (UIPageViewController *) self.parentViewController;
     [pvc previousPage];
}
```

My code in the `UIPageViewController`:

```
- (void)previousPage {
    UIViewController *vc = [self pageViewController:self viewControllerBeforeViewController:[self.viewControllers firstObject]];
    [self setViewControllers:@[vc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Do you know how I can solve this animation issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue.

I solved calling the method with a little delay:

```
func delayBlock(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

and then:

```
delayBlock(0.1){
                 self.setViewControllers([nextPageVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Give it a try and let me know!